What is the name of this sketch show, that this sketch is from?: "You got peanut butter on my chocolate." "You stole my land."
I remember this sketch from a comedy show. I believe I watched the show sometime between 2003-2008 (It might've been older and I was watching reruns). As well, I believe I watched it on The Comedy Network and that the show was either American or Canadian. I lived in British Columbia, Canada at the time. The show was in color and in English. 
I think it started with an interviewer discussing her/his next guest, a famous native american actor. They said he was famous for a few things and this commercial (Take all that with a pinch of salt, my memory is pretty fuzzy). They than showed the commercial.  
I believe it started with some white guy walking in a forest with a chocolate bar, he than bumps into the native american guy holding peanut butter. The white guy says, "You got your peanut butter on my chocolate." The native american guy says in a rather serious, dead pan fashion, "You stole my land."
